# How do we find the host name name by using mac address,VLAN or IP address on Layer3 switch

Tags: layer3

have quick question How do we find the host name name by using mac address,VLAN or IP address on Layer3 switch .

i pull up the vlan and mac address using my IP by i couldn't figure it out the host name of the layer2 switch

Comment: Unfortunately, host names are used by applications and protocols above OSI layer-4, so this question is off-topic here. You could try to ask it on [sf] for a business network, or on [su] for a personal network.

Answer (score 2):

You can't determine configured hostname by using IP or MAC. You can do it with CDP or LLDP, if protocol is enabled on interface of the switch.